# Orientation of Intersection of Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I am going through Guillemin and Pollack and have reached some difficulty with orientation. The way it does preimage orientations confuses me, and likewise the problems on the orientation of intersections of submanifolds.

I imagine to compute the orientation of $X \cap Z$, for $X,Z$ submanifolds of $Y$, I'm supposed to use the preimage orientation induced by the inclusion map $X \cap Z \hookrightarrow Y$. Is this correct?

He defines the preimage orientation as follows:

If $f:X \to Y$ is transverse to $Z$, then, the orientation of $S =f^{-1}(Z)$ is given by the following relations:

$$N_x(S; X) \oplus T_x(S) = T_x(X)$$
and
$$df_x(N(S;X)) \oplus T_{f(x)}(Z) = T_{f(x)}(Y).$$

So the idea must be, we can determine the orientation of $N(S;X)$ from the second relation, after deducing whether or not $f$ is orientation preserving or reversing, and then plug into the first one to find the orientation of $T_x(S)$? And the orientations "multiply" through (we just need the signs on both sides to be the same)?

Secondly, what is the standard orientation of a point? Oftentimes in problems, $X \cap Z$ is merely a point. For instance, if we take $X$ to be the $x-$axis, $Z$ to be the $y-$axis, and $Y$ to be $\mathbb{R}^2$. How would one go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. In your context - the preimage of $Z$ under the inclusion map $X \lefthookarrow Y$, not $X \cap Z \to Y$ (you don't have an oriented submanifold to pull back from)

2. Your intuition of how to determine orientation for $S$ is correct.

3. What if you try to put your intuition for orientation of $S$ to test? Remember that the preimage orientation assumes that $X,Y,Z$ are all oriented - which means even in the point case, you must pick an orientation for $X,Y,Z$ first

Comment: how do I pick an orientation for a point? Like when looking at $T_z(Z)$ where $Z= \{z\}$, a singleton